# Please consider merging most Meta "tag" tags

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

[retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request), [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms), [tag-request](/questions/tagged/tag-request) and [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) all seem identical to me.

Can someone with enough reputation suggest them as synonymous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do have different purposes. The wikis for each <del>should be</del> have been updated to reflect that.

- [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) is to request that one tag be renamed into another; this may also involve the creation of a synonym
- [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) is for questions about the tag synonym feature of Stack Exchange
- [tag-request](/questions/tagged/tag-request) is to request creation of a tag that doesn't currently exist
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) has no questions, so it should get cleaned up by an automated process

If people are misusing these that's a problem with their descriptions, not that they themselves are synonyms.

---

I have improved the wiki and excerpt for [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and the related [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request). [tag-request](/questions/tagged/tag-request) has been changed on most other Stack Exchange sites to [tag-creation](/questions/tagged/tag-creation); I've updated its wiki and excerpt and changed the three questions that had the old tag.

Comment: @pnuts: So, fix them.